# How to implement carousel in React Typescript

Tags: carousel, react-typescript

I have implementation of `react-responsive-carousel` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel in react js which is working fine. I need to convert into React TypeScript. I have introduced interface IResarousel where defined children and setting properties but getting error.

`error`

```
 Type 'ReactNode[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild[] | undefined'.
 Type 'ReactNode[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild[]'.
 Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild'.
 Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild'.ts(2322)
 types.d.ts(21, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Carousel> & Pick<Readonly<CarouselProps>, never> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'
 (parameter) children: React.ReactNode[] | undefined
```

`IResarousel`

```
interface IResarousel {
  children?: React.ReactNode[];
  settings: object;
}

export default IResarousel;
```

`Resarousel.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import IResarousel from '../../../interfaces/UI/IResarousel';

function Resarousel({children, settings} :IResarousel) {
  return (
    <Carousel {...settings}>
        {children} 
    </Carousel>
 );
}

export default Resarousel;
```

following model works fine as .js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

function Resarousel({children, settings}) {
  return (
       <Carousel {...settings}>
        {children} 
      </Carousel>
);
}

 export default Resarousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using TypeScript, it is recommended to use the `PropsWithChildren<Props>` helper type.

Remove the `children` property from your props' interface and then use:

```
function Resarousel({children, settings} :PropsWithChildren<IResarousel>) {
  // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The children prop of the Carousel component expects an array of **React.ReactChild** elements. but in your interface the the children prop defined as an array of **React.ReactNode** elements.
Refer the types from the react-responsive-carousel github repo: https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/master/src/components/Carousel/types.ts

Change your interface as in below:

```
interface IResarousel {
  children?: React.ReactChild[];
  settings: object;
}
```